# How are the iostate bits affected by fstream.close() and subsequent .open()?

Tags: c++

I've got an `ofstream` object which I'm periodically reopening, with a new filename. I know that `.clear()` resets the `iostate` to `goodbit`. However, it's not exactly clear to me if this state is affected by `.close` and `.open`.

In particular, can I check `.fail()` after `.close()` to determine whether I should `::remove` the file? I don't want to keep corrupted or partial files.

<strike>And if `badbit` and/or `failbit` are unaffected by `.close`, should I explicitly `.clear` them before calling `.open(newPath)` ?</strike> I already found out that the bits are cleared by `.open`, formally since C++11 but informally most implementations did it anyway.

Comment: Well, [`close`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/close) can set `failbit`, so it definitely can't clear any of the flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [ifstream.members] / 5:

> `void close();`
>
> Effects: Calls `rdbuf()->close()` and, **if that function returns a null pointer, calls `setstate(failbit)`** (which may throw `ios_base::failure` (27.5.5.4)).

Summing up [filebuf.members] / 6:

> `basic_filebuf<charT,traits>* close();`
>
> - If `is_open() == false`, returns a null pointer.
> - If any of the calls made by the function [...] fails, `close` fails by returning a null pointer.
> - If a put area exists, calls **`overflow(traits::eof())`** to flush characters.
> - If the last virtual member function called on `*this` (between `underflow`, `overflow`, `seekoff`, and `seekpos`) was `overflow` then calls **`a_codecvt.unshift`**
> - Finally [...] the function closes the file (as if by calling `std::fclose(file)`)

`overflow` ([filebuf.members] / 10) fails when:

- `codecvt::out` fails if `codecvt` "encountered a character it could not convert" ([locale.codecvt.virtuals] / 5).
- File output fails (unspecified, probably if `fwrite` fails on most implementations).

`codecvt::unshift` fails if "an unspecified error has occurred" ([locale.codecvt.virtuals] / 8).

`std::fclose` fails "if any errors were detected." (C11 7.21.5.1).

> In particular, can I check .fail() after .close() to determine whether I should ::remove the file?

As we have seen, `close` can fail if there is a problem with the file itself, or if codecvt comes across a character it cannot convert (or in the unlikely event that `unshift` fails). If you need to be absolutely sure that `close` failed because of a file issue, you will need to do something like `os.seekp(0, os.end).clear();` before closing to make sure that the only thing `close` does is call `std::fclose`.

Comment: Half an answer: it does say precisely when the bit can be set, but could it potentially be reset? The first sentence "_only if_" suggests the bit might be reset when `close` does _not_ return `nullptr`.